# Is there a way to calculate total from a MySQL Query?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to build a cart system. So far, I can pull the user cart data easily with some join and even calculate the total price based on unit price and quantity user has in another column. However, I wanted to know if there is a way to actually compute the total amount owed directly from an SQL query. Allow me to showcase an example. Here are my tables:

products

```
product_id | product_name  | product_price  |  stock
1          | Pasta         | 10             |  50
2          | Bread         | 2              |  100
```

cart

```
user_id  |  product_id  |  quantity
1        |  1           |  3
1        |  2           |  2
```

My Current Query

```
SELECT
    `cart`.`product_id`,
    `cart`.`user_id`,
    `cart`.`quantity`,
    `products`.`product_price` as `unit_price`,
    `products`.`product_name`,
    `cart`.`quantity` * `products`.`product_price` as `Total`
FROM `cart`
INNER JOIN `products` ON `products`.`product_id` = `cart`.`product_id`
WHERE `cart`.`u_id` = 1;
```

As you can see, the query above will work and return me all the products in the cart of a specific user and add the `Total` column to the result with the total price for each item.

Now, if I want to calculate the gross total, I have to read each row in my PHP code and do the total. Although I can do this, I was wondering if MySQL has a way of returning just the gross total directly through a single query.

Bonus question: Is a cart table structure like the one above good enough?

Comment: I see one issue in your solution. If product price will be changed, the cart cost will be changed too. It is not right practice. The cart cost should be fixed at purchase time an not be changed each product price update. So the `cart` table should be extended by `product_price` column that store price of product at purchase time.

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev That's a good catch, thanks! I had thought about it and completely forgot about it afterwards. I'll integrate this column asap.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "SUM" Operator in MYSQL to get the value from database directly.
Here is a documentation where you can get more info:
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sum/
[image]

Regarding the code here is an example:

```
SELECT SUM(`cart`.`quantity` * `products`.`product_price`) as `CartTotal`
FROM `cart`
INNER JOIN `products` ON `products`.`product_id` = `cart`.`product_id`
WHERE `cart`.`u_id` = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate total cart cost using `SUM` aggregation function.

```
SELECT SUM(`cart`.`quantity` * `products`.`product_price`) as `CartTotal`
FROM `cart`
INNER JOIN `products` ON `products`.`product_id` = `cart`.`product_id`
WHERE `cart`.`u_id` = 1;
```

Also you can use `UNION` construction for combine cart total result to main query like:

```
-- Get cart content for user
SELECT
    `cart`.`product_id`,
    `cart`.`user_id`,
    `cart`.`quantity`,
    `products`.`product_price` as `unit_price`,
    `products`.`product_name`,
    `cart`.`quantity` * `products`.`product_price` as `Total`
FROM `cart`
INNER JOIN `products` ON `products`.`product_id` = `cart`.`product_id`
WHERE `cart`.`u_id` = 1
UNION -- Union summary row to cart results
SELECT
    NULL as `product_id`, -- set NULL for non aggregated field
    `cart`.`user_id`,
    COUNT(*), -- calculate items count in cart
    NULL as `unit_price`, -- set NULL for non aggregated field
    'Total' as `product_name`, -- set 'Total' string as product name
    SUM(`cart`.`quantity` * `products`.`product_price`) as `CartTotal` -- calculate total cart cost
FROM `cart`
INNER JOIN `products` ON `products`.`product_id` = `cart`.`product_id`
WHERE `cart`.`u_id` = 1;
```